When $S^d/X$ is a manifold $S^d-X$ is homology equivalent to a point?
Upon reviewing for an algebraic topology final, I have found the following question which has stumped me: Let $S^d$ be a sphere of dimension $d\geq 1$, and $X\subset S^d$ a proper subset of $S$ such that $S^d/X$ is a manifold (whether this is supposed to be a smooth manifold or a topological manifold I am unsure), then it seems that $S^d-X$ is homology equivalent to a point.
For $S^d/X$ to be a manifold, we need $X\subset S^d$ to be a closed subset as otherwise
we would have a point $[x]\in S^d/X$ which is open, so $S^d/X$ couldn't be Hausdorff, but that's as far as I can get in determining what $X$ should be. I see that if $X$ is a point, or homeomorphic to a closed $d$-disk then we are golden because $S^d/X$ is homeomorphic to $S^d$ and $S^d-X$ is homotopy equivalent to $\mathbb R^n$ so is obviously homology equivalent.
I feel like the excision theorem could come into play here somehow, but I am unsure of how to do so. Any hints on how to approach this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Did you learn the Alexander duality in terms of the Chech cohomology? By the way, "homology equivalent to a point" is usually called "acyclic."

@MoisheKohan We did not. This question is from a past final that my professor did not teach, so maybe they di.

Here is one way to solve this problem. Assume that $M=S^n/X$ is a manifold, let $x$ be the projection of $X$ to $M$. Then $x$ has a basis of closed ball neighborhoods $V_i$. Let $W_i\subset S^n$ denote the preimage of $V_i$ in $S^n$. Then $\partial W_i$ is a (bicollared) $n-1$-dimensional sphere $\Sigma_i\subset S^n$. Now you use Alexander duality (which is better) or Mayer-Vietoris to conclude that the complement $S^n\setminus \Sigma_i$ consists of two acyclic components $U_i$ and $int(W_i)$. Hence, $A=S^n\setminus X$ admits an exhaustion by open acyclic subsets $U_i$. Since $H_*(A)\cong \lim_i H_*(U_i)$, we conclude that $A$ is acyclic.
